# What version number to put in JVM class files

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I'm writing a compiler that targets the JVM, using the ASM library to generate class files. JVM class files have a version number field and I'm trying to figure out what I should put there.

An obvious possibility would be, since I happen to be using Java 1.7, to put 51, the number corresponding to that version. However, to the best of my knowledge there's no reason somebody shouldn't be able to use my compiler to write programs targeting e.g. Java 1.6, so hardcoding that version number would break that use case.

Is there some minimal/baseline version number such that you can say "it's safe to use this, it marks the last actual change in the byte code format or JVM semantics and everything afterwards will support it"?

Conversely, maybe the best option would be to take the version number of the JVM the compiler is running under? If so, which of the many different Java version properties accessible at run time, should be used for this purpose?

Comment: The JVM is downwards compatible. 1.7 will also run bytecode with a version number smaller than 51. You should ask yourself what the minimal set of bytecode features that you require is and use the coresponding version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM is backwards compatible. Hotspot will accept versions as low as 45.0, which I believe dates back to before the official release of Java. (Java 1.03 was 45.3)

For manual bytecode manipulation, version 49.0 is the most useful because it is the last version to support jsr/ret and also doesn't require a StackMapTable.

The only reason you would use a later version is if you want to use `invokedynamic` in which case you need version 51.0. But that means you also have to generate StackMapTables, which is a big annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

> If so, which of the many different Java version properties accessible at run time, should be used for this purpose?

Pick the oldest version you are willing to support.  If there is a known issue with a version you can't fix, I wouldn't allow that version.

Which versions do you test?  If it is only Java 7, perhaps this is what you should set.

Do you use any of the JVM libraries?  If you do which is the minimum version they are available on?